# Match any action in custom route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to create a custom route map that allows me to match any action in a certain url mapping.
Example: `www.site.com/patient/records/treatments/23` where `treatments` could be any action in the pacient controller.

Here's what i have try but doesnt work:

```
  routes.MapRoute("records_ho", "{controller}/records/{action}/{recordid}", new {
            controller = "patient", recordid = UrlParameter.Optional
        });

  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "User", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

As you may have notice, i did not specify the action property in 'records_ho' and thats because I would like to avoid specifing in the MapRoute the 15 actions defined in the controller `Pacient`.

How can i achieve that?

Update:
Here is the action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Treatments(string recordid)
{
    // some code here...


    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko i dont know much about api routing with MapHttpRoute but yes, seems like it.

Comment: Did you test your own route? Just tried and have no issue with it on my side, e.g. was able to render `/patient/records/index/100` and `/patient/records/contact/100` with no issue. What error do you get?

Comment: Even without specifing the action property?

Comment: Please update your question with exception details to see what is going on.

Comment: what error are you getting ? what is not working?

Comment: @Usman the error is the code 404 Not found

Comment: @EinerSantana can you show the action which is not getting accessed

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code so only two MapRoutes are defined in the routing table?

Comment: See request/response in the answer below, something else is going on on your side e.g. older version of the routing lib, error in the code of the view or controller, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory everything should be working as expected, see below.

**Code of the routing:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/records/{action}/{recordid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "patient", recordid = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Code of the controller:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Treatments(string recordid)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**And the request/response:**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:29930/patient/records/treatments/23
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:29930
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1538
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 21 Apr 2017 20:42:02 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: I was testing passing the parameters with the ?. thats why it was not maching anything. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, sharing problem with somebody else always helps!